# Where are the PHP error logs stored on a Debian 8 "Jessie" server?

Tags: linux, debian, php, error-logging

I know this question has been asked many times before, and I've looked at all the answers but they don't seem to work for me. I am trying to check if the error log is turned on for PHP, so I went to the php.ini file and uncommented the line in the picture seen below.

[image]

I tried using the "whereis" command to find where php_error.log is but it returned a line that had "php_error:          " and nothing else. Is that the correct way to view/turn on the php error logs? If not how do I and can I redirect them to an easier folder to access such as my home folder?

Also, I understand that there are many different types of errors, but do I need to configure all of their paths or do they automatically go to the same error log?

As a side note I have apache2 installed. I've seen a lot of questions relating php and apache2 and I'm not sure why so does the way to handle error logging?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that there are multiple ways to run PHP scripts when they are accessed via a web server, and logging depends on that.  To rephrase, whatever runs PHP, maintains the logging.

On my Jessie (Debian 8) systems I run PHP using `php5-fpm` and it has logging configured in `/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf` (but that can be overridden for each so-called "pool" `php-fpm` uses).

On older systems it was customary to run PHP using `mod_fcgid`, and in that case the `php5-cgi` binary is used to actually run the scripts, and it reads its configuration from `/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini`.

Some folks still use `mod_php` to run PHP scripts, and in this case something like `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` is used by that module.

To round up, the configuration depends on the way you serve calls to PHP scripts, so figure that out first, and then work from there.

A hint: if you do have PHP minimally working, create a simple site which serves a single script reading

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

access that script and see what PHP engine prints about its configuration — including places it acquired this configuration from.